# MeteorJS - click.increment function not working (Your First Meteor Application)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm working through the book *Your First Meteor Application* and I'm stuck on Section 8.3: *Advanced Operators, Part 2*

Basically, the `click.increment` and `click.decrement` functions are supposed to do the following:

- On click, the name of the player (li element) the background transitions to yellow
- When clicking the "Give 5 Points" or "Take Away 5 Points" the user's points are incremented / decremented by 5.

However, here's what's happening:

- when I click on a player (li element) it is highlighted yellow
- when I click on the increment or decrement buttons, the li element is de-selected, the background is no longer yellow, and there is no change in the number of points.

Any help would be appreciated.  This must be a very simple matter that I've overlooked but I can't figure it out.

Here's the relevant code:

**leaderboard.html:**

```
<head>
  <title>Leaderboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>The Leaderboard</h1>
  {{> leaderboard }}
</body>

<template name="leaderboard">
  <ul>
    {{#each player}}
      <li class="player {{selectedClass}}">{{name}}: {{score}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
    <input type="button" class="increment" value="Give 5 Points">
    <input type="button" class="decrement" value="Take 5 Points">
</template>
```

**leaderboard.js:**

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');

console.log("Hello World from Meteor!");

if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.leaderboard.helpers({
    'player': function(){
        return PlayersList.find();
    },
    'selectedClass': function() {
        var playerId = this._id;
        var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
        if (playerId == selectedPlayer) {
          return "selected";
        }
      }
  });

  Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click.player': function() {
        var playerId = this._id;
        Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
    },

    'click.increment': function() {
        var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
        PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer, {$inc: {score: 5} });
      },
    'click.decrement': function() {
        var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
        PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer, {$inc: {score: -5} });
      }
  });
}
```

**leaderboard.css:**

```
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a space in your event declaration:

```
'click .player': function() {
```

Your code working:
http://meteorpad.com/pad/WofZFR5vjrDck4YRK

Comment: I don't know how I missed that.  Thank you.